# Material appears different after being assigned to the same object

Tags: modeling, materials

[image]

I've applied a material to my floor in this room model, but for some reason after being assigned to the object, parts of it appear stretched?
I tried moving around the origin point, but that had no effect.

Comment: are you using an image texture, and if so, how are your UV map in the UV Editor?

Comment: What happens if you apply the scale? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/apply.html

Comment: It looks like you stretched the UV map while modifying your floor object

Answer (score 1):

Try go into *Edit Mode* when the floor object is selected. Select all the faces by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> . Then unwrap it again by selecting *Cube Projection* from the UV menu.